# Spring 5 web service client issue with SOAP marshaling

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, soap, jaxb

When I try to call a web service with generated wsdl classes SOAP request is wrongly generating.

Ex: SOAP request is generating with xmltype(names="xxx") instead of generating with @XmlElementRef(name="aaa") for arrays. this is causing XML validation issues on server side.

Same is working in old version of spring 4.x web.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by checking ObjectFactory class. It has different createXXX for xmltype and XmlElementRef. We need to identify correct QName and use while building jaxb request class.